# AWS CodePloy pipe example repository : "bash: zip: command not found"

Tags: aws-code-deploy, bitbucket-pipelines

I tried to follow the [Deploy to AWS with CodeDeploy](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/deploy-to-aws-with-codedeploy-976773337.html) instruction

and used the [bitbucket-pipelines.yml](https://bitbucket.org/bitbucketpipelines/example-aws-code-deploy/src/master/bitbucket-pipelines.yml)

But I'm getting this error:

```
cd app && zip -r ../myapp.zip *

+ cd app && zip -r ../myapp.zip *
bash: zip: command not found
```

Can I do anything about it?

Comment: I also [asked](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-Pipelines-questions/AWS-CodePloy-pipe-example-repository-bash-zip-command-not-found/qaq-p/1243881) their community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example repository the docker image is configured to atlassian/default-image:2 in the [bitbucket-pipelines.yml](https://bitbucket.org/bitbucketpipelines/example-aws-code-deploy/src/7e460d66be1fdeb7c80053be5de97bdf32cd8a2e/bitbucket-pipelines.yml#lines-1)

```
image: atlassian/default-image:2
```

If you use another docker image to run the pipeline, the zip CLI can be missing and you'll need to install it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`

```
- apt-get update
- apt-get install -y zip
```

right before the

```
- cd app && zip -r ../myapp.zip *
```